# Android Java INSERT INTO mysql database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

What is the best way for Android Java to INSERT INTO the database?

I dont know how to start, the only thing I know is that I need a connection to the database, prepare a statement for the database and execute the sql.

Comment: Show the php code

Comment: You question is not about using Java to insert into database, it is using Java send a request and using PHP to handle the request **and** insert into database.

Comment: You sir or ma'am is correct, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo the variable $id in PHP. Your query seems fine to me, so there has to be a problem with passing the id variable from android to PHP. If you make a POST request and the id is successfully passed to web service, then there is a problem with your query.

In case you cant pass the variable, try this code:

```
        HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Append parameters to URL
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.appendQueryParameter("id", "your value");
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        // Open connection for sending data
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        conn.connect();
```

You can see your PHP echo by using these lines after your connection:

```
            InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(result.toString());
```

For an SQL query in PHP, you can use PDO (save your DB connection credentials in variables as used in example):

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_servername;dbname=$db_dbname", $db_username, $db_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM anything";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```